# How to open a display on Git Bash

Tags: terminal, git-bash

I am using Git Bash on a Windows machine. Whenever I try to open a display, I get the error "DISPLAY NOT OPENED." Is there something that I need to download in order for it to work? I have a friend that uses a Unix machine and she needs x11 in order for the display to open. Is there an equivalence of that for Windows?

Comment: No. There is no alternative on Windows. What are you trying to open?

Comment: What do you mean by "display" ? I don't understand what you are trying to do ...

Comment: Sorry. I am kind of new to all of this. There's a program that I run, and it supposed to open a new terminal that has some graph on it. That's what I mean by display.

Answer (score 0):

> she needs x11 in order for the display to open. Is there an equivalence of that for Windows?

No with git bash alone.

You need to install an X11 emulator separately.
For instance [XMing X server](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/), that you would launch like so:

```
Xming.exe -ac :0 -clipboard -multiwindow
```